# A journal for the article related to methods for solving Cauchy equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms, numerical-methods

I'm a postgraduate student in physics, but I have achieved interesting results in Cauchy equation. I found a reason why Adams method for solving differential equations gives rise to divergent solutions. I explained this phenomena and provided a new improved integration schema. Could anybody help me to choose a good mathematical journal where I can publish my results?